# How do I extract the diagonals as strings from a two-dimensional array of characters?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to programmatically solve the word puzzle below as an exercise for myself:

```
puzzle = [
    ['t', 'r', 'o', 'l', 'l'],
    ['u', 'u', 'a', 'a', 'y'],
    ['n', 'r', 'r', 'e', 'q'],
    ['a', 'o', 'h', 'd', 'q']]
words = ["troll", "tuna", "nut", "oral", "turd", "deal", "rut", "hey", "ear"]
```

But I need a little help with completing the exercise. Here's what I've done so far:

I convert the rows and columns into single strings and put them into a list:

```
a = []

#Rows
for x in puzzle:
    a.append(''.join(x))
    a.append(''.join(x)[::-1])  #Append reversed string.

#Columns
for i in range(len(puzzle[0])):
    s = ""
    for j in range(len(puzzle)):
        s += puzzle[j][i]
    a.append(s)
    a.append(''.join(s)[::-1])  #Append reversed string.
```

So now I can find any word spelt horizontally or vertically. As you might have guessed the next step is to go through the diagonals and put them into the list, but just can't figure out the logic to do it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at the indices of all the elements in the nested lists:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4)
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4)
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4)
(3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4)
(4,0) (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4)
```

From this you can write down the indices for the top half of the diagonals to get a sense of the pattern:

```
(0,4)
(0,3), (1,4)
(0,2), (1,3), (2,4)
(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)
(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)
```

How do we generate these lists of pairs? First, let's look at the outside loop. The outside loop will go across the top of the first sublist, i.e. the pairs `(0,j)` where `j` counts down from the last index:

```
for j in range(len(puzzle), -1, -1):
    print((0, j))

#output:
(0, 4)
(0, 3)
(0, 2)
(0, 1)
(0, 0)
```

Then we need to have our inner loop go down and to the right on each step, and to never go past the end of the list:

```
for j in range(len(puzzle), -1, -1):
    for i in range(len(puzzle)):
        j += 1
        if j > len(puzzle):
             break
        print((i,j))
    print("")
```

Output:

```
(0, 4)

(0, 3)
(1, 4)

(0, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 4)

(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

If you make the outer loop go from `N..-1` then you can also get the diagonal that passes through the center. After that, use similar logic to get the bottom half of the diagonals.

To get the diagonals going in the other direction you can again use the same kind of logic (by looking at what indices you want, writing the outer loop, then writing the inner loop), or you can just reverse each of the sublists (think of it as looking at the mirror image, or reflecting a 2d array over a vertical line! when you do this, all the diagonals will be going through the elements in the "opposite" direction).

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

1. words found in rows are sequences `puzzle[a][b+i]`
2. words found in columns are sequences `puzzle[a+i][b]`
3. words found on diagonals are sequences `puzzle[a+i][b+i]` or `puzzle[a+i][b-i]`

for `i=0,...,n`, each for some integers `a,b,n` such that all the indices produced are in the table. You can check the sequences forwards and backwards. Additional constraints, such as only considering complete rows, are acheived by placing constraints on `a,b,n`. In particular, the way I interpret it is that you want the longest possible strings in each case; in this case, you just set `n` to the largest possible value for each `a,b`.

You already have 1. and 2. down. I recommend you start with your solution for the columns and try to apply it to the sequence described in 3. instead.