# How to check for specific values diagonally in a 2D list if height and width may vary

Tags: python, nested-lists

I was writing a program like tic tac toe.

**Explaination**

I wanted to make a function that would take input as a 2D list of *n x m* length where n may or may not be equal to m.

It will have to check whether or not there are 4 consecutive X's or 4 consecutive O's anywhere in the *2D list*.

It should return "X" if there are four adjacent "X" values anywhere in the list (*row, column,diagonal*).It should return "O" if there are four adjacent "O" values anywhere in the list (row, column,
diagonal).It should return None if neither 'X' nor 'O' satisfy the above condition. You may assume that there may only be one answer.

If i give follwing **input**:

```
xwins = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
         [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
         [None, None, None, None, "X" , None, None],
         [None, None, None, "X" , "O" , "O", None],
         [None, "O" , "X" , "X" , "O" , "X", None],
         ["O" , "X" , "O" , "O" , "O" , "X" , "X"]]

owins = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
         [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
         ["O" , "O" , "O" , "O" , None, None, None],
         ["O" , "X" , "X" , "X" , None, None, None],
         ["X" , "X" , "X" , "O" , "X" , None, None],
         ["X" , "O" , "O" , "X" , "O" , None, None]]

nowins =[["X" , "X" , None, None, None, None, None],
         ["O" , "O" , None, None, None, None, None],
         ["O" , "X" , "O" , "O" , None, "O" , "O" ],
         ["O" , "X" , "X" , "X" , None, "X" , "X" ],
         ["X" , "X" , "X" , "O" , "X" , "X" , "O" ],
         ["X" , "O" , "O" , "X" , "O" , "X" , "O" ]]

print(myfunc(xwins))
print(myfunc(owins))
print(myfunc(nowins))
```

It should give **result**:

```
X
O
None
```

My **progress**:

I have only found a way to check in each row by using code:

```
def myfunc(lol):
    for i in lol:#lol is list of list :)
        string="".join(i)
        if ("XXXX" in string):
             return "X"
        elif ("OOOO" in string):
             return "O"
```

I am trying to do without numpy.

Help will be appreciated. Sorry if i left anything unclear. Please ask me in comments. :)

Comment: The first algorithm could be an exhaustive search. I.e. iterate over all diagonals longer than 3 and count if there are consecutive 'oooo' or 'xxxx'. As a hint, you can get the first column by selecting all first elements, i.e. `lol[:][0]`

Comment: i cant understand how to iterate over diagonals

Comment: c.f. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764211/how-do-i-extract-the-diagonals-as-strings-from-a-two-dimensional-array-of-charac) and many other useful answers.

`for ii in range(len(lol)):
    for jj in range(len(lol[ii])):
        if ii = jj -a:
              # code here
`

Comment: There are so many diagonals so i dont understand how can i check all of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that for solution in columns:

```
vert = ["" for i in range(len(lol[0]))]
for i in range(len(lol)):
    for j in range(len(lol[i])):
        vert[j] += str(lol[i][j])
for column in vert:
    if ("XXXX" in column):
        print("X")
    elif ("OOOO" in column):
        print("O")
```

It creates with elements from columns, and checks if there is a required pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest algorithm is to simple check every direction by iterating over it.

You asked about diagonals specifically. We have to indexes, one in the x-direction(inner list), one in the y-direction (out list),  lets call them `ii` and `jj`.

The simplest diagonal is the one in the middle. You are on this diagonal when `ii == jj`. What about the diagonals parallel to that? `ii + 1 == jj` and `ii - 1 == jj`.

For a given  diagonal, `ii + a == jj` will be true for a being a integer defining which of the diagonals you are defining.

Then a similar argument applies for diagonals starting from the other side `ii + a = n - jj`

Comment: what if i am starting for the edge . Then ii - 1 == jj shouldnt work

Comment: The equations define all diagonals that exist on a grid. You will want to check all those that fall within `0 <= ii < n, 0 <= jj < m`

Comment: Ok. It seems hard to understand . Some code may help :)

Comment: I'm not going to solve your problems for you without you attempting to solve the problem yourself. Create a loop over all values of `a` (between what values should `a` be?) and then for each value of `a` loop over `ii` and `jj`, considering only the cells that fit the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but I used Numpy like so:

First, turn the matrix in to numpy.array

```
lol = np.array(lol)
```

Get the dimensions

```
rows, cols = lol.shape
```

Check the rows and columns by iterating through them like so

```
for i in range(rows):
    if "'X' 'X' 'X' 'X'" in np.array_str(lol[:, i]):
        return 'X'
    ...and so on
```

You can iterate through the diagonals using the np.diagonal function:

```
for i in range(rows):
    if "'X' 'X' 'X' 'X'" in np.array_str(np.diagonal(lol, offset=i)):
        return 'X'
    ...and so on
```

You can get the diagonals on the different direction with e.g. `offset=-i`. Then you can do the same for the transpose, which you get with `np.fliplr(lol)`. You can also figure out a limit for the offset, since you don't need to evaluate the diagonals shorter than 4.

Comment: Thanks for answering however i was trying to do without numpy